# MM/DD/YYYY Java Program

Tags: java, date

thanks for helping!

I was wondering if there was any way to just get user input for Month (1 string), Day (2 integers), and Year (4 integers). Sorry - this is probably EXTREMELY basic, but I'm a beginner in Java and am completely lost.

I also don't know how to declare strings and assign "values" to it. If someone could just give one line of code to do so I would be very grateful.

My programming assignment is to take this user input and print it out to the screen as Month/Day/Year - all I need is how to get the actual user input - I can do the rest on my own.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy");
       System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
}
```

Comment: These terrible date-time classes have been supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. See `LocalDate` class instead.

Answer (score 3):

try  following code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy");
       System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your Hint.

```
//First of all import Scanner to read user input
import java.util.Scanner;

//Now in main Create a String object and Scanner object
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String month;                                      // How to declare Strings

// Read user input using Scanner and assign that to String

month = sc.next();                                 // How to assign values to Strings

// Do same of date and year (data type of date should be int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's complete code along with user input and relevant `date` conversion:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException, NumberFormatException, IOException{
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter Day:");
        int day=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter Month:");
        String month=br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Year:");
        int year=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy").parse(""+day+month+year);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
```

**Output :**

```
Enter Day:
15
Enter Month:
aug
Enter Year:
2014
Fri Aug 15 00:00:00 IST 2014
```

Comment: It even calculates the day of the week? Sweet! Thanks for all your help Darshan.

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

For the month name, if in English, [change to all uppercase](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()) and use to retrieve a [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum object.

```
Month month = Month.valueOf( "January".toUpperCase() ) ;
```

Combine with your year and day-of-month to get a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) object.

```
int year = 2019 ;
int dayOfMonth = 23 ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( year , month , dayOfMonth ) ;
```

To generate text, you can specify a custom formatting pattern with a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Or you can let that class [automatically localize](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate(java.time.format.FormatStyle)) for you.

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:

  - The *human language* for translation of name of day, name of month, and such.
  - The *cultural norms* deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.US ;   // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH, Locale.JAPAN, etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = 
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT )
    .withLocale( l )
;
String output = ld.format( f );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).